# How can I add a Julia project to the Jupyter Lab launcher?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia, jupyter-lab

new to Julia.

Problem:

I know how to set Python and R env in Conda and add those to Jupyter Lab.

It seems that Conda does not work smooth together with Julia like it does with Python.

The environments are listed then in the Jupyter Lab launcher by adding IPython.
I also know how to set up Julia on the machine and install it in Conda env.
I can work with Julia on Jupyter Lab.
The Julia 1.8 icon is showing in the launcher.
However, if I want to generate a project / env in Julia I use the Julia REPL.
I can install packages directly in the root env, and it works in Jupyter Lab.
But how can I add the project, not the root, env to Jupyter Lab and make up show up in the launcher.

The best approach I did find was:

```
julia --project=. -e "using IJulia; notebook(dir=pwd())"
```

This does not work.
Is it possible to add Julia env to Jupyter Lab and make those appear in the launcher?

Thanks for advice.